# Excel matching and copy to

Tags: excel

In Excel in Column A I have a range of data. In Column D the same data exists along with many other rows. I want to look for a match between column A and D and if there is one copy the data in column C that is adjacent to the found match in column D to column B on the same row as the searched item in column A

Comment: I can't completely understand the problem, can you plase provide us few rows for example?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you just need a `INDEX/MATCH` formula. You can enter the following formula at `B2` and fill down the column:

```
B2
=INDEX(C:C, MATCH(A2,D:D, 0))
```